# Proving that $xf'(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}(x+1)f(x+1) - xf(x) - \frac{1}{2}xf''(ξ)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

**Exercise :**

> Let $f:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that $f \in C^2$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} xf(x) = 2$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} xf''(x) = 0$. If $x>0$, prove that for some $ξ \in (x,x+1)$ it is 
>   $$xf'(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}(x+1)f(x+1) - xf(x) - \frac{1}{2}xf''(ξ)$$
>   and then calculate the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} xf'(x)$.

**Question/Request :** I need some help, hints or tips on **how to prove the formula in the center of the question**. The final limit asked is simple as you just use the formula proven, so no help needed on that.

Comment: Is the first term in the right-hand side what you meant to write? Because then $x+1$ would cancel out.

Comment: @ε-δ Was weird enough on when I was copying it from my textbook, but yes, according to it, this is the form of the expression.

Comment: why do you write $\frac{x}{x+1}(x+1)f(x+1)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you would write the identity in this peculiar why, but this is just Taylor's theorem on the interval $[x,x+1]$. Since $f\in C^2$, the theorem guarantees the existence of $\xi\in(x,x+1)$, so that $f(x+1)=f(x)+f'(x)+\frac12f''(\xi)$. Multiply by $x$ and you're done.